# Itunes connect doesn't recognize screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

In a new version of my app I've added support for apple watch. I am trying to add some screenshots but the message on the image attached keeps appearing. I've tried to reupload, upload one or five screenshots but nothing works. It still says that there are issues and the version could not be submitted.
I've heard about an issue that screenshots need some time to be processed but it's not the case, since I'm waiting for six hours now.

What could be the issue? What can be done to fix the issue and finally send the newer version to the app store?

*Note, screenshots were taken on 42mm watch simulator.
[image: Your binary indicates support for Apple Watch. You must provide an Apple Watch screenshot.]